# Python BrokenProcessPool for the code, how to resolve this?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple code which was working fine in Mac. I tried in another Mac and Windows laptop but getting the error shown below.
Can someone give me help?

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA8Ig.png)

Comment: Please include your error message in your post in text form.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
e process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Comment: for full msg, click on the Error msg link in my original post.